# Peer registration does not see Global Cloud

Tags: c#, cloud, p2p, peer

I am playing with the very simple P2P features and when I get the list of the available Clouds:

```
foreach (Cloud c in Cloud.GetAvailableClouds()){ ...}
```

I don't see a Global Cloud, only LinkLocal.
My computer has the internet access and the tutorial shows that I should see both, but I don't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It might help to indicate which library you are using.

Comment: I am using System.Net.PeerToPeer

Comment: Besides, I can use netsh with the same result